# Calling a DIV twice using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using [Subscribe2](https://github.com/abhas9/subscribe2) and it works great. The form is called using the `<div id="element"></div>`

However, it shows once per page. I want to show it twice on the same page. One at the top of the page and another at the bottom. How should I go about it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#element").subscribe2({
            options: {
                    method: "google",
                    formkey: "2eiFxDZOpcyjPo9ub7nIwp6vAKUkLIiOxXIPT1TtAAAA",
                    datakey: "entry.57553044"
                },
            });
        });
```

Comment: instead of using `id` use `class` 

<div class="element"></div>

because targeting id can only be done once.. so just add <div class="element"></div> at and bottom of your page..

Comment: Thank You. I didn't know id can be done only once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you.

Since there are no CDN repository for subscribe2, I have added the files in the custom script/css only.

```js
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var pluginName = "subscribe2",
        defaults = {
            buttonText: "Request Invite",
            btnClass: "",
            inputClass: "",
            errorMessages: {
                client: "Please enter a valid email address.",
                server: "Error contacting server"
            },
            successMessage: "Thanks. We have added you to our list and you will be notified soon."
        };
    // Plugin constructor
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        if (!options.hasOwnProperty("options") || typeof options.options !== "object" || !options.options.hasOwnProperty("formkey") || !options.options.hasOwnProperty("datakey") || typeof options.options.formkey !== "string" || typeof options.options.datakey !== "string") {
            console.error("Invalid Options. Refer https://github.com/abhas9/subscribe2");
            return;
        }
        
        this.element = element;
        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }
    // Avoid Plugin.prototype conflicts
    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
        init: function() {
            this.appendSubscribeBox();
        },
        postForm: function(inputValue) {
            var data = {}, that = this;
            data[this.settings.options.datakey] = inputValue;
            var successCallback = function() {
                that.inputView.css({
                    display: "none"
                });
                that.successMessage.css({
                    display: "block"
                }).html(that.settings.successMessage);
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" + this.settings.options.formkey + "/formResponse",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                statusCode: {
                    0: successCallback,
                    200: successCallback
                },
                data: data
            })
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            var inputValue = $(this.element).find(".subscribe2-control-input").val();
            if (this.validateEmail(inputValue)) {
                this.errorMessage.css({
                    display: "none"
                });
                this.postForm(inputValue);
            } else {
                this.errorMessage.html(this.settings.errorMessages.client).css({
                    display: "block"
                });
            }
        },
        inputKeyUp: function(event) {
            var inputValue = $(this.element).find(".subscribe2-control-input").val();
            if (event.which === 13) {
                this.submitHandler();
            } else {
                this.errorMessage.css({
                    display: "none"
                });
                if (this.validateEmail(inputValue)) {
                    this.validationStatusIcon.css({
                        display: "block"
                    }).addClass("subscribe2-valid").removeClass("subscribe2-invalid").html("&#x2713;");
                } else {
                    this.validationStatusIcon.css({
                        display: "block"
                    }).addClass("subscribe2-invalid").removeClass("subscribe2-valid").html("x");
                }
            }
        },
        validateEmail: function(value) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(value);
        },
        appendSubscribeBox: function() {
            var subscribeInputWrp = $("<div>", {
                class: "subscribe2-input-wrp"
            });
            var subscribeInput = $("<input>", {
                type: "email",
                class: "subscribe2-control-input " + this.settings.inputClass,
                placeholder: "Email",
                keyup: this.inputKeyUp.bind(this)
            });
            this.validationStatusIcon = $("<div>", {
                class: "subscribe2-validation-status",
                css: {
                    display: "none"
                }
            });
            subscribeInputWrp.append(subscribeInput, this.validationStatusIcon);
            var subscribeButton = $("<button>", {
                text: this.settings.buttonText,
                class: "subscribe2-btn " + this.settings.btnClass,
                click: this.submitHandler.bind(this)
            });
            this.errorMessage = $("<div>", {
                class: "subscribe2-error",
                css: {
                    display: "none"
                }
            });
            this.successMessage = $("<div>", {
                class: "subscribe2-success",
                css: {
                    display: "none"
                }
            });
            var clearDiv = $("<div>", {
                css: {clear: "both"}
            });
            this.inputView = $("<div>", {
                class: "subscribe2-input-view",
                append: [this.errorMessage, subscribeInputWrp, subscribeButton, clearDiv]
            })
            var subscribeBox = $("<div>", {
                class: "subscribe2-wrp"
            });
            $(this.element).append(subscribeBox.append(this.inputView, this.successMessage));
        }
    });
    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);


$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".element").subscribe2({
            options: {
                    method: "google",
                    formkey: "2eiFxDZOpcyjPo9ub7nIwp6vAKUkLIiOxXIPT1TtAAAA",
                    datakey: "entry.57553044"
                },
            });
        });
```

```css
.subscribe2-wrp {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.subscribe2-input-view {
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

.subscribe2-input-wrp {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    position: relative;
}

.subscribe2-btn {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.subscribe2-control-input {
    width: 100%;
}

.subscribe2-validation-status {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
}

.subscribe2-valid {
    background: #49BF49;
    border: 1px solid #6DBD6D;
}

.subscribe2-invalid {
    background: #c0392b;
    border: 1px solid #B13326;
    line-height: 9px;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

.subscribe2-success {
    padding: 10%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .subscribe2-input-wrp {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .subscribe2-btn {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="subscribe2/src/jquery.subscribe2.css">
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element" id="footer"></div>
```